# Handling Logs/Transactions of huge volume

Tags: logging, cassandra, ibm-mq, bigdata

We have a Multi-threaded Enterprise application that is deployed in three different data centers and they receive XML messages in queues from an upstream system. The Volume of data that is being drained by the application is very huge and the logs that the system writes is in order of 200GB/hour. The Logs are maintained for a very shorter period of time. The application basically, writes to cassandra DB / IBM Extreme Scale Grid / Oracle DB. Now the exact issue, is that, we don't have a track on the transactions that are received/processed by the application. Said that, There are a lot of data synch up issues with the upstream systems and we don't have a way to track whether we recived/processed the message successfully after a period of time. We also don't have capacity to save the messages or redirect logs to any Big data file system because of the infrastructure limitations we have. Is there a way that this issue can be addressed. Please give in your comments and suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For problem determination, the easiest and simplest method is to make sure every XML message has a unique transaction id.  Hence, your application logs/stores the transaction id and not the whole XML message.  When there are issues then you compare the transaction ids for which one(s) is/are missing.  And transaction id that is missing, you have the sender application resend the XML message.